# Mysql request in PHP, with a value from a cookie ;

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

The following code in PHP doesn't work since I replaced numbers like 2 or 3 by ".$_COOKIE['minLat']."     (or maxLat, or MinLng...)

Cookies, in the console.log, seems to work:

```
minLat=47.62467785241327; maxLat=48.45835188280866; minLng=-1.4117431640625002; maxLng=5.7073974609375
```

they were loaded before the error in the console. The error is :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

It's in the last lines of the query that I updated my code. the rest is fine. The error is in

```
AND i.latitude > ".$minLat."  AND i.latitude < ".$maxLat."
         AND i.longitude > ".$minLng."  AND i.latitude < ".$maxLng."
```

Could you help me put the cookies data into the Mysql query?

```
$minLat = $_COOKIE['minLat'];
$maxLat = $_COOKIE['maxLat'];
$minLng = $_COOKIE['minLng'];
$maxLng = $_COOKIE['maxLng'];


$query="SELECT i.latitude, i.longitude,
    IFNULL(i.name, '') AS `name`,
    IF(i.representative_ext IS NULL,
        CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM i.path), '.', 1 ), '-sq.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM i.path), '.', -1 )),
        TRIM(LEADING '.' FROM
            REPLACE(i.path, TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(i.path, '/', -1 )),
                CONCAT('pwg_representative/',
                    CONCAT(
                        TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(i.path, '/', -1 ) , '.', 1 )),
                        CONCAT('-sq.', i.representative_ext)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS `pathurl`,
    TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM CONCAT( i.id, '/category/', IFNULL(i.storage_category_id, '') ) ) AS `imgurl`,
    IFNULL(i.comment, '') AS `comment`,
    IFNULL(i.author, '') AS `author`,
    i.width
        FROM ".IMAGES_TABLE." AS i
            INNER JOIN (".IMAGE_CATEGORY_TABLE." AS ic ".$INNER_JOIN.") ON i.id = ic.image_id
            WHERE ".$LIMIT_SEARCH." i.latitude IS NOT NULL AND i.longitude IS NOT NULL
    AND i.latitude > ".$minLat."  AND i.latitude < ".$maxLat."
             AND i.longitude > ".$minLng."  AND i.latitude < ".$maxLng."


           ".$forbidden." GROUP BY i.id;";
```

Comment: Print out `$query` and run it through a query tool where you can inspect it

Comment: @ChrisHaas my query tool in Phpmyadmin, doesn't have the cookies value of a webpage.

Comment: I know. That’s why I said to print (echo, dump, etc.) the query itself out, with the intention of those variables applied, and then run the query.

Comment: @ChrisHaas. ok. should I do that in the console or in the code ? I'm a beginner in php but starting to watch this closely, i'll be  googling on this

Comment: In the code. Instead of executing the SQL query, just `echo` it. Don't echo anything else out it and `exit` immediately after echoing it. Then view source and copy and paste from that window just to ensure no accidental browser interpretation happens. You can see a sample of what I mean [here](https://3v4l.org/R27mk). That said, please know that this is **very insecure**. Once you get the query working, look into prepared statements, this kind of code is very vulnerable and trivial to exploit.

Comment: ok thanks. I guess echo sends all returned info in the webpage. my "map" div of https://mappingforyou.eu/france has no room for that, its div has 100% width and height. so I still have no result, or perhaps for another reason. I'd love to have this echoed in the console

Comment: The console is for JavaScript, not HTML. For this specific thing, temporarily erase everything except the query so that's the only thing you see. Copy that, then undo.

Comment: @ChrisHaas '' : success: i'll keep you posted.